# Pros and Cons of named instances for development

Tags: sql-server

Is it advisable to create a named instance on the same server for my developers?  We need a development environment for testing.  We have SQL Server Express, but the limit of 10GB is not enough.  We need about 50GB for testing and don't want to spend the extra amount on full blown SQL. What are the pros and cons of having a named instance on the same server 2017 for the development?

Comment: SQL Server Developer Edition is completely free for development work starting with 2017 version. What do you mean by `don't want to spend extra amount on full blown sql`, are you trying to save on OS licences / hardware?

Comment: Yes, I don,t wont to pay OS licences / hardware?.

Comment: Generally it is not a good idea to run multiple instances of SQL Server on the same machine. Having said that, Express edition is so [restricted in terms of resource limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15) that even a desktop machine can support multiple instances without any problems. As @RogerWolf said, download Developer edition and install it locally on each developer machine. It is free.